# Implement NSUndomanager in tutorial code

Tags: ios, nsundomanager

trying to implement undo function in smooth drawing app that I did following this tutorial

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk_freehand-drawing/

From what I read, using NSUndoanager is the best way of doing it, but I am not seeing how to implement it in the code. Should I put the – prepareWithInvocationTarget: in drawBitmap?

Thanks.

Comment: have a look at this   
1) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8249506/difficulty-implementing-nsundomanager-redo-function  
2)http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616946/how-to-implement-undo-using-nsundomanager-newbie-question

Comment: This might be helpful: Apple's "DotViewUndo" sample code. It's a tiny project with undo/redo: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/DotViewUndo/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008851-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2

Comment: hey can you please tell me how did u implement the undo in this drawing application ?